# How to manipulate query value output?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Suppose in an SQLite table the data in a row is `1`. I need to display on my GUI that `1` as an `YES`.

How to achieve that?

This is my code:

```
QString name = ui->comboBox->currentText();
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "conn_name");
db.setDatabaseName("/usr/share/SGLogs/"+name);
db.open();

if (db.open()) {
    qDebug()<<"DataBase is Open" << name;
} else {
    qDebug()<<"DataBase is Not Open";
}

QSqlQueryModel * model = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("conn_name"));
query.exec("SELECT id,has,date,time,device,username,dn,v,p,s FROM d_e");
model->setQuery(query);
query.exec();

if (query.exec()) {
   while (query.next()) {
        ui->View->setModel(model);
        ui->View->setColumnHidden(0, true);
        model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("DATE"));
        model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("TIME"));
        model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("DEVICE"));
        model->setHeaderData(7, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("V"));
        model->setHeaderData(8, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("P"));
        model->setHeaderData(9, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("S"));
        model->setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("USER"));
        model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("DN"));
        model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("HAS"));
    }

    db.close();
    qDebug()<<"DataBase is Closed"<< name;
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("conn_name");
} else {
    qDebug()<<"DataBase Table Not Open";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `case` expression to transcode the value of your column. Assuming that the concerned column is `col` in table `mytable`, you would do:

```
select t.*, case when col = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as new_col
from mytable t
```

Comment: is this use before execute query?

Comment: @Gaurav: this *is* the query that you want to run.

Comment: Ok, Will try. Thanks GMB

Comment: Please help! complete this question

Comment: Got it! Thanks GMB